# Javascript blocks other javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I purchased a document on www.themeforest.com, which generated a function like:

```
<!-- Start Live Chat Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.testsite.com/support/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery5524f88f85aa4 = $.noConflict();
        jQuery5524f88f85aa4(document).ready(function($) {
            $.get("http://dev.testsite.com/support/", function(data) {
                $("body").append(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
<!-- End Live Chat Code -->
```

But this code is blocking  the other Javascript functions in my document. Does anyone have a idea how i could i fix this?

For example navigation dropdown's wouldnt work anymore etc.

Comment: call the author of the script ask him what to do !!

Comment: do your study/reading/research and try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: By "block", do you mean you're getting an error?

Comment: I don't see any reason this should interferer with any other scripts? (Assuming your not getting some sort of jquery conflict from potentially having two copies? - if this is the case I'd just remove the jQuery from the above snippet and let it use your central one.)

Comment: Could you post an abbreviated version of the page source. It'll show where other scripts are in relation to the auto-added one.

Comment: For example, Without this codesnippet in the post everything would work fine. The navigation pops out and in etc. But if i add the code snipped. The navigation items pop out but nothing pops in anymore.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QAjPVSfd

Comment: And when the snippet is included, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: It might be a conflict with window.onload (lines 32 to 39). Comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: Still the same sadly, the console only returns: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: jquery-easy.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function inside of this document: http://dev.pr0b.com/support/assets/js/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you wrap this inside a try catch block like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
    var jQuery5524f88f85aa4 = $.noConflict();
    jQuery5524f88f85aa4(document).ready(function($) {
        $.get("http://dev.testsite.com/support/", function(data) {
            $("body").append(data);
        });
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
</script>
```

If this JS snippet is causing an exception that is blocking other JS on the page then you will be able to catch that using this `try..catch`

Comment: Yes, give me a second.

Comment: scripts.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function inside of this document: http://dev.pr0b.com/assets/js/scripts.js

Comment: @pr0b Can you check if its printing the error stack inside the catch block ?

Comment: To pin down this is the issue can you comment out entire content of  dev.pr0b.com/assets/js/scripts.js and check if it works ?

Comment: I just deleted two files, called: <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and it worked. The error came from those documents.

Comment: undefined is not a function is what it said

Comment: This error poped up in those 2 documents. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I think in both those files you were trying to make use of a jQuery plugin. `$("a selector").search()` for example. I think your $ is getting clobbered somehow.

Comment: If possible can you add similar try..catch in these two files for the entire code.

Comment: I am trying to get a trace so that you know which function is exactly causing this.

Comment: One second ill check it quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<!-- Start Live Chat Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.testsite.com/support/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery5524f88f85aa4 = $.noConflict();
    jQuery5524f88f85aa4(document).ready(function($) {
        $.get("http://dev.testsite.com/support/", function(data) {
            $("body").append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- End Live Chat Code -->
```

To this:

```
<!-- Start Live Chat Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.testsite.com/support/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.get("http://dev.testsite.com/support/", function(data) {
            $("body").append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- End Live Chat Code -->
```